# How to know if my XML Sitemap being submitted?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I've configured the XML Sitemap and Site verification modules, but I don't see the sitemap being submitted to Google. If I enter the Google Webmaster tools it says no sitemaps were submitted, but maybe it doesn't show those posted via API or something.

How could I know if it's being actually submitted? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure these two modules will do the submission?  I always do it manually in my GWT, Yahoo and Bing accounts.  Spiders will find them anyway, even if you don't submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 7, it will show that your sitemaps have been submitted in your log messages at Admin > Reports > Recent Log Messages (/admin/reports/dblog)

Click on "Filter log messages" and select "xmlsitemap"

If you do this, it will show when the last sitemap was generated and when it was submitted the the search engines that you have configured it to submit to (in my case, Google and Bing).